# Iron Python Code Analysis

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I have the below code of Iron Python to be used in Spotfire. From my understanding it can refresh particular data table. There is a commented part which seems to have a counter. I need an explanation on how the counter works and whether the existing code just refreshes the data tables.

Iron Python Code:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataManager

myDocument=Application.Document
#myDocument.Properties["RefreshCounter"] = 0



DM = Application.GetService(DataManager)
DM.Tables.Refresh([table1, table2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in Spotfire something like document property defined as below.
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/other/other_details_on_new_edit_document_property.htm
So developer seem to intended to just count have many times the refresh happened but in the code I dont see the moment where he increment the counter so it might have beeen deleted instead of commented out. Just an educated guess.

The code just refreshes the table. As per http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/10/refresh-reload-datatables.html

Comment: Thanks. i got the right code. But i am unable to implement it. When i tested it with a local file it dint work. To do the refresh i have to embed in a button and on click of the button it should work right. It would help me if you give me the correct steps or example of how you implemented it in real time

Comment: Could you explain in more detail. What do you mean by implement in real time. What exactly did you accomplished already and what is missing ?

Comment: i enabled the script 'if table.IsRefreshable and table.NeedsRefresh:
    table.Refresh()' in a button in the text area. When i click the button nothing happens. is it possible to enable the script without button and to make it run in certain intervals. If not at least i want to make sure that the script enabled in the button is working properly when i click on it. I verified this using a real time file and when the file was added with new row and when i hit refresh button it dint work. Need your assistance